# Using python, how do you repeatedly extract regularly formated chunks of text from .txt file, and write them to multiple, separate files?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose you have a text file with a bunch of contacts information, (e.g. name, phone, email etc. ) for multiple people.

Using the example information below and python (and perhaps regex), how would you extract the bundled information for each person and write it to an new file? The result would be that you have a separate text file for each person with only their info...

So, the input text looks something like this:

```
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah

name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah

name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
```

Comment: can't you just split on `'\n\n'`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: depends, how big is your file? does it fit easily in memory?

Comment: Yep, it'll easily fit.

Comment: Also, are the `(newlines)` empty lines? (would be better to provide the real format)

Comment: They are empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file easily fits in memory, you can simply split on `\n\n`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for n, chunk in enumerate(f.read().split('\n\n'), start=1):
        with open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(chunk)
```

`file.txt`:

```
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah

name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah

name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
```

output files:

`chunk_1.txt`

```
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah
```

`chunk_2.txt`

```
name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah
```

`chunk_3.txt`

```
name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
```

For larger files, you can use a more classical loop, adding the lines one by one in the new files, changing file when you encounter a blank line:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    n = 1
    f_out = open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w')
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            f_out.write(line)
        else:
            f_out.close()
            n+=1
            f_out = open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w')
    f_out.close()
```

output:

```
==> chunk_1.txt <==
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah

==> chunk_2.txt <==
name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah

==> chunk_3.txt <==
name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another neat implementation with regex.

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'name::\s*(?P<name>.+?)\nphone::\s*(?P<phone>\d+)\nemail::\s*(?P<email>.+?)\naddress::(?P<address>.*?)\nnote::\s*(?P<note>.*?)')

with open('/original_file.txt') as f:
    people = pattern.finditer(f.read())
    for person in people:
        person_info = person.groupdict()
        with open(f'person_{person_info.get("name")}.txt', 'w+') as w:
            for key, value in person_info.items():
                print(f'{key}:: {value}\n', file=w)
```

This approach matches all lines of the file with a single regex pattern. The regex pattern parses all of the individual fields, so you can also pick every one of these fields like this `person_info.get('phone')`.