# How do you append the same text to multiple txt files in python?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine you have some text that you want to split into chunks and send to separate files which are named using l'mahdi's solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992458/using-python-how-do-you-add-incremental-timestamps-to-txt-file)

But imagine there is a header at the top of the file:

```
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah
timestamp::

name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah
timestamp::

name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
timestamp::
```

How do you append the header to each file so we get the following files?

```
# chunk_1.txt
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-07-15 (15h 12m 25s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1


# chunk_2.txt
name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-07-15 (15h 12m 26s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1


# chunk_3.txt
name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
timestamp:: 2022-07-15 (15h 12m 27s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Split the text on `\n\n` or whatever and then loop over then and each time write to a file

Comment: What is your actual question?  How to read a file?  How to read "chunks" of content from a file, separated by blank lines?  How to write to a file?

Comment: First: can you count on the file format being as shown, with exactly one blank line between the header and the first entry, and exactly one blank line between each entry?  Second: when you read the file into memory, how are you planning to do it?

Comment: How to do you append the following?

Comment: company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

Comment: To John Ladsky: yes and see the l'mahdi's solution.

Comment: It feels like you're asking us to write this exact program for you, instead of asking for general knowledge to allow you to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the header firstly, you can try my solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    header, content = f.read().split('\n\n', maxsplit=1)
    for n, chunk in enumerate(content.split('\n\n'), start=1):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d (%Hh %Mm %Ss)')
        chunk = re.sub(r'(timestamp::)', fr'\1 {timestamp}', chunk)
        chunk = chunk.strip() + '\n' + header
        with open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(chunk)
        time.sleep(1)
```

And here is the result:

```
# chunk_1.txt

name:: Joe Blogs
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 08s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

# chunk_2.txt

name:: Josephine Blogs
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 09s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

# chunk_3.txt

name:: John Smith
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 10s)
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

Comment: You may have just solved a student's homework.  But you may have solved it in a way that any attentive teacher would ask the student how they understand regexes and the python internal library so well.  :^)

Comment: Thank you Son. If you are interested to know: I'm not a student, this problem is an abstraction of a real problem, not somebody's homework. Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate it.