# How do you cut text from a line and append it to another line in text file using python?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine you have some text that you want to split into chunks and send to separate files, using [Son Huang's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265230/how-do-you-append-the-same-text-to-multiple-txt-files-in-python) based on [l'mahdi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992458/using-python-how-do-you-add-incremental-timestamps-to-txt-file)

Suppose the given text is modified such that the lines starting with `note::` have some additional text before a comma, and each chunk of text has another line, starting with `highlight::`:

INPUT

```
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: highlight text, blah blah blah
timestamp::
highlight::

name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: Another highlight here, More blah blah
timestamp::
highlight::

name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Amazing text, Some more blah
timestamp::
highlight::
```

What needs to be added to [Son Huang's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265230/how-do-you-append-the-same-text-to-multiple-txt-files-in-python) to get the following result? You can see that the text before the comma on the line starting with `notes::` now appears on the line starting with `highlight::`(and the comma is gone)

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
# chunk_1.txt

name:: Joe Blogs
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: blah blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 08s)
highlight:: highlight text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

# chunk_2.txt

name:: Josephine Blogs
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: More blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 09s)
highlight:: Another highlight here
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

# chunk_3.txt

name:: John Smith
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Some more blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 10m 10s)
highlight:: Amazing text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question by clearly showing the sample input followed by the output you expect.

Comment: can you not simply check if its an empty line and if so, split it there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Inputs and outputs are clearly shown and link to Son Huang's solution is provided.

Comment: You should at least make an attempt of your own.

Comment: @quamrana Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: I think it is acceptable because you will see that Son Huang has built his solution using code that I helped build. It seemed redundant to re-post that code. I have a complex problem that have abstracted into a form that people might relate, and have been slowly altering it one step at a time.

Comment: Sorry, this is not your own personal IDE. It is a site where you ask specific questions about your own code. You should make an attempt at a change, post that, and show how it’s not quite right yet.

Comment: What are the rules that govern the values associated with *highlight* and *timestamp*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating [Son Hoang solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265230/how-do-you-append-the-same-text-to-multiple-txt-files-in-python)

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    header, content = f.read().split('\n\n', maxsplit=1)
    for n, chunk in enumerate(content.split('\n\n'), start=1):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d (%Hh %Mm %Ss)')
        chunk = re.sub(r'(timestamp::)', fr'\1 {timestamp}', chunk)

        # Regex partition of 3 groups for line note::: i.e. 1. (note:::\s+), 2. ([^,]+) and 3. (.*)
        note = re.search(r'(note::\s+)([^,]+),(.*)', chunk)

        # Note without 2nd group (i.e. \1 & \2 only)
        chunk = re.sub(r'(note::\s+)([^,]+),(.*)', fr'\1\3', chunk)

        # Add 2nd group from note::: to highlight
        chunk = re.sub(r'(highlight::)', fr'\1{note.group(2)}', chunk)

        chunk = chunk.strip() + '\n' + header
        print(chunk)
        print()
        with open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(chunk)
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Input**
*File: test.txt*

```
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: highlight text, blah blah blah
timestamp::
highlight::

name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note:: Another highlight here, More blah blah
timestamp::
highlight::

name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note:: Amazing text, Some more blah
timestamp::
highlight::
```

**Output**
*File: chunk1.txt*

```
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note::  blah blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (04h 59m 56s)
highlight::highlight text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

*File: chunk2.txt*

```
name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note::  More blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (04h 59m 57s)
highlight::Another highlight here
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

*File: chunk3.txt*

```
name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note::  Some more blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (04h 59m 58s)
highlight::Amazing text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```

Comment: I got an error message for line 18: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @supposer --  The error indicates it did not find the substring. in chunk.  Is the input file as shown in my answer?

Comment: No, my input file is different. The order of lines is different, and the highlight text is a sequence of numbers, letters, and parentheses.

Comment: @supposer -- are you saying your input does not correspond to the "INPUT" in your posted question?

Comment: That's correct. I had to modify the content to protect IP. The entire problem as described is a fiction that borrows  the form of my actual problem.

Comment: I did it with you input text exactly and got the same error.

Comment: I got it to work by using a try, except block.

Comment: @supposer -- strange I don't get an error with my text.  Do you have blank chunks?  But, your solution of try/except solves the problem.  Alternatively you can place an `if note:` statement after re.search.  This would only do the processing if the search is successful.

Comment: I'm so grateful for you help. I think I'll stick with the try-except. Just one more quick one: how do I separate the highlight value from the `::` with a space. As is, the text is flush up against the `highlight::`. Thanks DarrylG

Comment: no there were no blank chunks.

Comment: I got it; you leave a space as follows: `fr'\1 {note.group(2)}'`. All good. Thanks so much for you your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to parse the data properly, and edit it that way. If you just want a quick and dirty solution, this would work though.

You could loop over each line and check if it starts with `'note:: '`, then split it based on the first comma.

I'm assuming that your data structures are unordered, so it's ok if I output the properties in a slightly different order.

```py
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('note:: '):
        highlight, remainder = line.split(', ', 1)
        highlight = highlight.removeprefix('note:: ')
        # Write note and highlight as separate lines
        output(f'note:: {remainder}')
        output(f'highlight:: {highlight}')
    elif line.startswith('highlight::'):
        # Skip the original highlights
        pass
    else:
        output(line)
```

In this case, output should be replaced to match the function you're using to write to your output file.

Keep in mind that this code isn't super robust though - if you want this to be reliable you should definitely create a system for parsing this data properly.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should work fine for you. Do optimize the solution as per your convenience:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re

with open('input.txt') as f:
    header, content = f.read().split('\n\n', maxsplit=1)
    for n, chunk in enumerate(content.split('\n\n'), start=1):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d (%Hh %Mm %Ss)')
        chunk = re.sub(r'(timestamp::)', fr'\1 {timestamp}', chunk)
        
        substitute1, substitute2, substitute3 = ("note:: ", "\n", "highlight::")
        idx1, idx2 = chunk.find(substitute1), chunk.find(substitute2, chunk.find(substitute1))
        text_chunk = chunk[idx1 + len(substitute1): idx2] #.split('\n')
        lst_chunk = text_chunk.split(',')
        chunk = re.sub(text_chunk, '', chunk)
        chunk = re.sub(r'(' + substitute1 + ')', fr'\1 {lst_chunk[1].strip()}', chunk)
        chunk = re.sub(r'(' + substitute3 + ')', fr'\1 {lst_chunk[0].strip()}', chunk)
        
        chunk = chunk.strip() + '\n' + header
        with open(f'chunk_{n}.txt', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(chunk)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
#chunk1.txt
name:: Joe Blogs 
phone:: 123456789
email:: joeblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note::  blah blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 56m 52s)
highlight:: highlight text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

#chunk2.txt
name:: Josephine Blogs 
phone:: 43217890
email:: josephineblogs@email.com
address:: 123 Main Street
note::  More blah blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 56m 53s)
highlight:: Another highlight here
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1

#chunk3.txt
name:: John Smith 
phone:: 23498689
email:: johnsmith@email.com
address:: 1 North Street
note::  Some more blah
timestamp:: 2022-08-07 (13h 56m 54s)
highlight:: Amazing text
company:: acme products
department:: sales
floor:: 1
```